# TinyMCE element out of place on custom WordPress page

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, editor, admin, positioning

I am creating a small custom test administrator page in WordPress and when I insert a `wp_editor` command the textarea was displayed on the top of the working area?

Unfortunately no CSS was able to restore it to its correct position. Any help or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Image of the problem]

Edit: Thank you for your quick reply I am writing the very simple code below. As you can see it is nothing super, just a test:

```
    function TstPlg_PageDisplay() {
      $MyPage = '
      <div class="wrap">
        <h2>TestPlugin</h2>
        <p>This is a test for the TestPlugin Page</p>
        <hr>
        <div>
          '.wp_editor('','MyTextArea').'
        </div>
      </div>';
      echo $MyPage;
    }
    function TstPlg_AddMenuPAge() {
      add_menu_page( 'TstPlg_PageDisplay', 'Test Plugin', 'manage_options', 'TstPlg_PageDisplay', 'TstPlg_PageDisplay');
    }
    add_action ('admin_menu', 'TstPlg_AddMenuPAge');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems (it's hard without code), that the textarea is echoed and the plugin code is outputed directly.

To avoid this you can use ob_start(), ob_get_clean() and after echo the result (textarea) where you want.